# How do I add an exception to an existing HttpForbiddenHandler rule in web.config?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Here is my web.config file. This configuration denies access to all users from accessing the pdf files, but I want to add an exception where an ASP.NET page can access PDF files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <caching>
            <profiles>
                <add extension=".css" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
                <add extension=".inc" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
                <add extension=".html" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" />
                <add extension=".asp" policy="DisableCache" kernelCachePolicy="DisableCache" duration="00:00:30" />
            </profiles>
        </caching>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="pdf" path="*.pdf" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>

        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
            <allow users="test" />
        </authorization>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

For example, a `viewpdf.aspx` can access/load all pdf files.

Can I create an exception in web.config where I can do this?